# Looking for solutions about htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Don't know why my htaccess code doesn't work... any solutions ?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I just want have urls w/o .html & .php, and nothing else ;p

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Edit:

On one blog I found that some servers need

```
Options -MultiViews
```

before RewriteEngine On. Use it with our original code.

Comment: When i put this code i get error 500 on all of the pages ;P

Comment: still errors... tommorow will contact to my server support ;]

Answer (score 0):

Default Laravel **.htacces**s configuration works in most cases. Unless you made some changes, specific to you server.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I've put this code but nothing happend after that... maybe I should write to my server support ;p

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite conditions only get applied to the immediately following rule, that means the second rule that you have doesn't have any conditions and will blindly rewrite **everything** to include a `.php` at the end, even files that already have a `.php` at the end. The rewrite engine also loops, so it doesn't matter if the first rule matches or not. The resulting URI will continue to have all the rules applied to it until it stops changing, which in your case is never. Thus you get a 500 error no matter what.

Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```